# $http.get load after rest code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to load data from http.get like this:

```
$http.get("/riddles").success(function(data){
    $scope.riddles = data;
    $scope.riddlesCount = $scope.riddles.length;
});
```

And if I call `console.log($scope.riddles)` outside this function, `$scope.riddles` is undefined, but if I call `console.log($scope.riddles)` inside `$http.get`, `$scope.riddles` is that what I want. I have also a function:

```
$scope.test = function() {
    console.log($scope.riddles);
}
```

And when I call it using ng-click, when app load, its work correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: because that is how asynchronous calls work. It is like ordering a pizza. You want to eat the pizza as soon as you place the order. You can't you need to wait.

Comment: "outside this function" == "before the function has been called"

Comment: Well, it's simply because `success` (even though now it should be `then`) only executes when the call is done. If you call your `console.log` outside, the http call is not done yet and `$scope.riddles` is not initialized.